# Cannot open file 'pgort.llib' after adding /GENPROFILE flag

Tags: windows, visual-studio, pgo

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/profile-guided-optimizations?view=vs-2019) to add PGO for my project. After I added the `/GENPROFILE` flag, I start getting the link error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'pgort.lib'
```

After debugging it a bit, I believe the problem is that my **Library Directories** (found under **VC++ Directories** tab) has a value of `$(VC_LibraryPath_x64);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)` which is evaluating to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\spectre\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\atlmfc\lib\spectre\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\lib\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\lib\um\x64
```

It looks like the `.\spectre\x64` paths don't have the `pgort.lib` library, but the non-spectre path does:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64
```

What do I do to fix this? I find it hard to believe that if I'm using the spectre binaries (which I am not even sure how/why I am in the first place) that I can't optimize my project.

BTW, I tried this on a machine with Enterprise VS installed and it's the same. So this isn't specific to Community edition.

Comment: Just copy it, can't imagine how it is critical to spectre counter-measures.

Comment: This is an open source project that a few people work on, so I'd like to have some automated approach here. I was considering setting the LibraryPath to `$(LibraryPath);$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Desktop)` when compiling for PGO.  But you think I should just copy pgort.lib into the spectre folder as a part of my build script (if not already there)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up updating my build configuration/scripts to dynamically update the `LibraryPath` to add the appropriate, architecture-specific version of `$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Desktop)` when compiling for PGO.